# Rails + React-I18next : can't find locales/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, i18next, react-on-rails

I want to integrate React-I18next in my React on Rails app (i'm using webpack).

The problem is react-i18next can't find my locales folder...
Where can I put my locales ?
in the public folder of rails ? (not working..)
i create a new public folder in my javascript folder ? (not working..)

I am a beginnner of webpack and I don't really know what is it, but maybe i need to add my locales folder to webpack public folder ?

I don't know..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I find the answer..
You need to put your locales folder in public/ of your rails app (public/ is located at the root of your app).